# php json read with rest post

Tags: php, json, rest, web-services

I can send a `json` request with this code. But How can I read json request in with php http://www.test.com/post . it is my doman

```
function try($method_name, $json_data)
{
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.test.com/post');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data)));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
    $diziyap = json_decode($result);
    if ($diziyap->Success==1) {
        $sonuc = [1,''];
    } else {
        $sonuc = [0,json_decode(json_encode($diziyap->Errors), true)];
    }
    return $sonuc;
}

$sonuc = try('try', $json_data);
echo "<pre>";
echo $sonuc[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read json with rest post request you need to use `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Use below code:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json_data);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: @nFnK If your problem is solved then you can assign as right answer.